# Does making a GET request to get a captcha and then making a POST request to post the response change the original captcha?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to login using python requests. I make a GET request and get the captcha. I solve the captcha and then i make a POST request with the necessary payload. But the captcha has changed (or has it not ?) so my response is incorrect. I'm using Session but even that isn't working. Any suggestion/help is appreciated.

```
    session = requests.session()
    prox = {'http':'socks5h://localhost:9050',
            'https': 'socks5h://localhost:9050'}
    session.proxies = prox
    em_url = 'http://b4lzbnzx55o7d6yutrhrbgku35fl3hy6r7eyx7veorw6qwih27covjid.onion/'
    response = session.get(f'{em_url}')
    doc = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

    form = doc.find('form').find_all('div')


    name = form[0].find('input')['name']
    pswd = form[1].find('input')['name']
    img = form[3].find('img')['src']
    cap = form[4].find('input')['name']

    print(img, '\n\n') # I get the url of the captcha
    cap_ans = input() # Giving captcha's output manually for testing

    payload = {
        name:'myUsername',
        pswd:'myPassword',
        cap:cap_ans,
    }


    login_wrap = form[5].find_all('input')
    hid_data = []
    for x in login_wrap:   # There are some hidden inputs too
        payload[x['name']] = x['value']


    resp = session.post(f'{em_url}', data=payload)
    print('status', resp.status_code)
    print(resp.text) # I should be logged in now, but that doesn't happen and i get an invalid captha error
```

Comment: Please kindly read some tips for asking SO questions: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How do you know it's not working? Can you prove it to us? See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: With many of these kinds of questions there is usually javascript involved and `requests` does nothing to help you there. See [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) and the [tag:selenium] tag.

Comment: I've added the code snippet. The reason for my confusion is that I've manually multiple times entered the captcha to the script with an input() statement and all of them went incorrect.